# AngularJS Function within Function

Tags: angularjs, function, methods, callback

I have a notifications dropdown in my AngularJS application. I want to call a function within the function that open the dropdown. Here is what I mean:

```
$scope.showNotif = false;

    $scope.toggleNotifDropdown = function(event) {
        $scope.showNotif = !$scope.showNotif;

        readNotifications = function() {
            NotificationService.readNotifs().then(
                function(success) {
                    console.log("Notifications read!");
                },
                function(errors) {
                    console.log("Something wrong happened.");
                }
            );
        };

        if($scope.showNotif) {
            $document.bind('click', $scope.globalNotifClose);
        } else {
            $document.unbind('click', $scope.globalNotifClose);
        }

        event.stopPropagation();
    };
```

The notifications dropdown works perfectly, I just can't get that function readNotifications() to work for me. Any suggestions would be great! Thanks!

Comment: Are you ever invoking `readNotifications()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no point in declaring the function within your scope function and you never call it either. Declare it outside and call it from inside

```
$scope.toggleNotifDropdown = function (event) {
    $scope.showNotif = !$scope.showNotif;

    //  call the function declared below
    readNotifications();

    if ($scope.showNotif) {
        $document.bind('click', $scope.globalNotifClose);
    } else {
        $document.unbind('click', $scope.globalNotifClose);
    }

    event.stopPropagation();
};

// function declaration
var readNotifications = function () {
    NotificationService.readNotifs().then(

    function (success) {
        console.log("Notifications read!");
    },

    function (errors) {
        console.log("Something wrong happened.");
    });
};
```

Comment: YES! Thank you! I totally forgot about calling the function. Having a weird morning. Thanks!